# Why are images from newly created folder not showing up?

Tags: android, camera, image-gallery

In my app i have an option to take a picture, which will be saved in the folder:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/my-images";
```

Images are being saved fine, and i also have an option to select image which uses this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

**here initially it used to show 2 galleries**

**1. Camera**

**2. my-images**

picking any of them etc.., all worked fine.

but for no reason i deleted the my-images folder and ran the application again. The same folder is created again and images are getting saved as expected.

**The problem is:**

my-images gallery is not showing up now, when i click the select images button.

Except for deleting the my-images folder and restarting the application, i haven't changed any code since it used to work well.

why is it so?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

*my activity code, which allows user to take a picture and store on SD card, and browse image gallery:*

```
public class PictureFromAppActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    private File dir;
    private Bitmap photo;
    private String encodedString;
    private InputStream is;
    private ImageView imagePreview;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imagePreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
        Button takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_a_picture);
        Button selectImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_picture);

        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }
            }
        });
        selectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                if (data != null) {

                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    Bitmap bitmapOrg = photo;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
                    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();

                    try {
                        encodedString = Base64.encodeBytes(ba, 0);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                    }

                    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                            .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                        File imagesFolder = new File(
                                Environment
                                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                "/my-images");
                        if (!imagesFolder.exists()) {

                            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
                        } else {

                        }
                        String fileName = "image_" + count + ".jpg";
                        f = new File(imagesFolder, fileName);
                        while (f.exists()) {
                            count++;
                            fileName = "image_" + String.valueOf(count)
                                    + ".jpg";
                            f = new File(
                                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                            + "/my-images", fileName);
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                    f.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(ba);
                    o.flush();
                    fo.close();
                    try {
                        File imageFile = new File(
                                Environment
                                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                        + "/my-images" + "/image_" + count + ".jpg");
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile
                                .getAbsolutePath());
                        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        Log.d("Image Width", "+" + imagePreview.getWidth());
                        Log.d("Image Height", "+" + imagePreview.getHeight());
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(PictureFromAppActivity.this,
                            PictureFromAppActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

                if (data != null) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    try {
                        File imageFile = new File(selectedImagePath);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile
                                .getAbsolutePath());
                        imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                } else {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri selectedImageUri) {

         String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be that is because of the gallery is associated with your application and its keeping the view with it.
So what is happening when you delete image/folder it been deleted from the system but the media gallery is not updated which is associated with your application.
Please use below code and let me know if this solves your problem

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Please use this code to open images from gallery

```
intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO);
```

And in your on activity result

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String path = "";
switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               Uri uri = data.getData();
               path = pathFromUri(uri); // Now you can get the path of your selected image from here
           }
        break;
        }
    }
```

getting path from URI code

```
/**
     * Method to get path from uri
     * 
     * @param Uri
     *            uri
     * @return String path
     * */
    private String pathFromUri(Uri uri) {
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null,
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }
```

Comment: You have to use this code while opening the library to view images or folder created by you. This piece of code just send broadcast to refresh your sdcard and library to view your folder/images

Comment: so before calling the intent to open gallery??

Comment: its still showing images only from the default camera gallery which is SD/DCIM/Camera. But not the SD/Pictires/my-images folder. which also contains few images

Comment: done. Please check the edited portion of my question.thank you

Comment: Please check my edited code and use it in your selectImage button

Comment: i should use this "sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(Environment
 .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/my-images")));" before the intent in my selectImage button onClick??

Comment: i did this. but nothing seems changed :(

Comment: okay. i used the exact code you posted. It works now. Initially it shows only the default images gallery, then says "Loading.." and shows my-images folder.

Comment: actually intent of opening gallery is little bit wrong and its just taking to you a specific folder if you you the edited code that I have supplied you will get all the images available in the device in the gallery and you can select it and get the required image

Comment: fine.thanks a lot. is it refreshing(loading) images only or the whole sd card content and then fetch only images?

Comment: we are not specifying anything like, refresh only image galleries. it that fine?

Comment: Well you can do that but I used this code to refresh my gallery every time when it is being opened in my project. I found this code while googling, you can modify and check it according to your needs